# How do I view a webapp in an application and call it up with a hotkey?

Tags: windows, browser, website, hotkeys

I frequently visit a web app hosted on a nearby server, usually via browser bookmarks. I'd like to have a hotkey to "launch" it in an application with *none* of the browser toolbars or menus, since the web app can take care of its own navigation.

How can I do this? Chrome can place [URL shortcuts](http://www.nirmaltv.com/2008/09/03/how-to-set-up-application-shortcuts-in-google-chrome/) on your desktop, but I'd like to know my options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Firefox**

Start FF with the -profilemanager command line switch and create a new profile. Set up this profile to now have any chrome at all (Most can be turned off, try Hide Menubar to get rid of the top bar).

Now, grab a copy of AutoHotKey, and try something like this:

`#w::Run p:\ath\to\firefox.exe -P "Profile Name (Case Sensitive)" "http://url.to/webapp"`

This would launch firefox, without chrome, at your webapp.

Comment: +5 - This is amazing because I can get a minimal installation of Firefox opening up with the homepage set to my webapp's URL, instead of a bloated thing running with Prism, though Prism sounds like an integrated solution.

Comment: Why the downvote, whoever? Always willing to improve myself :)

Answer (score 2):

If using Firefox, check out the [Prism](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/6665) (a Mozilla labs project).

Side Note: if using Windows, you can assign a shortcut hotkey to any desktop icon.

Comment: oops, I didn't realize there was a time limit. I was still typing this one when you accepted the other one :-)

Comment: No time limit :D its just that I thought no one had anything else to answer.

Answer (score 1):

Google Chrome fans can create application shortcuts to achieve this. This [release note](http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2008/09/try-gmail-in-google-chrome.html) talks specifically about Gmail, but it will work with any website.

> **Application shortcuts**: You can create an application shortcut to access Gmail straight from your desktop. Simply go to Gmail while you're using Google Chrome, click the page menu and select 'create application shortcuts.' When you double-click a shortcut icon, it opens in a streamlined window.

It's also worth noting that Prism/WebRunner is not under active development, so Chrome app shortcuts will continue to get all the improvements that Chrome gets, and you con easily find a download link for chrome (currently, not so easy for Prism/WebRunner).

In Chrome > Click the Wrench Icon > Tools > Create Application Shortcuts...

Create the shortcut on the desktop, right click the shortcut, and set up a shortcut.

Answer (score -2):

You can use the free [Visual Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/vcsharp/) and make your own .NET-application to display you webpage using the built in WebBrowser-control. It's not that hard even if you are not a programmer, you can find instructions [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/WebBrowserControl11102005042132AM/WebBrowserControl.aspx). The WebBrowser control uses the Internet Explorer engine. When making your own application you are in total control of the layout of the window, don't need any menubars etc. Then you can assign a hotkey to start your application.

[image]

You can of course hardcode the URL to your WebApp instead of using the textbox and browse-button in the image above.

Comment: This is a average user solutions website...solutions that require the user to write a program probably don't belong here.